# Are Wookiee Life Debts officially non-canon for Star Wars 'nouveau'?

Tags: star-wars, chewbacca

Does anyone know if the Wookiee Life Debt concept is officially no longer part of Star Wars lore? I know the term "Wookiee Life Debt" was NOT mentioned in any Episodes, just in games (such as KOTOR).

I'm sure there's already a question about Chewbacca's motives for leaving Han so quickly when he fell, but I was just wondering if anyone specifically knows if the concept of a Wookiee Life Debt even exists in the new Star Wars canon.

Comment: ...there's a new canon book with the words literally as the title

Comment: @NKCampbell - Yousa been havin' the life play with thissen hissen?

Comment: ppppppbbbbbtttttt...........@Valorum

Comment: Had my time of 'hating' Star Wars Noveau.. but I'm realizing Star Wars is basically the last thing we got. I wish they had focused on Chewie's separation from Han a little more, etc. (Maybe i'm finally getting too old.)

Comment: "Just in games"? I take it you never read any of the novels? Chewie's life debt is probably mentioned at least once in every Legends novel he appears in.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The concept of a Wookiee "*life debt*" is fully canon in the new Disney franchise.

For example, in the novel [Star Wars: Aftermath - Life Debt](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Aftermath:_Life_Debt), we get the following passage from Han about Chewie

> “He’s a Wookiee, right? Kashyyyk, that’s where he comes from, that’s
>   his home. But it’s not his anymore. I’ve been there. I’ve seen what
>   the Empire has done. They ripped down the trees. They put cuffs and
>   collars on all the Wookiees. Some of them they cut open. Others they
>   ship off to work the worst jobs the Empire has on offer. They took his
>   home from him. I can’t abide that. I don’t have a home anymore besides
>   the Falcon, but him? He does. And he deserves to go home. He has a
>   family, too, you know.
>
> “I saved him, at least that’s what he says, the big fuzzy fool, but
>   really, he saved me. I was on a bad path, and Chewie, he put me
>   straight. Saved my shanks more than once, too. **He said it was part of
>   some life debt—he has a word for it, but if I try to say it in his
>   tongue I’ll probably strain something.** Even if I can’t say it, I know
>   what it means. It means that he owes his life to me.
>
> “But that’s a hot cup of bantha spit, is what it is. He doesn’t owe
>   me. I owe him. I got a debt to Chewie to get him his home back. So
>   when this chance came up, I leapt at it. The rebels, or the Republic,
>   or whatever they want to call themselves? They didn’t want any part of
>   it. I made it clear, we need to make Kashyyyk a priority, but they
>   waved me off. Not strategically significant, they said. Not yet. Soon.
>   Blah blah. Bureaucracy and strategy and war planning? They made me a
>   general but I didn’t know a thing about any of that. I don’t follow
>   what’s on some…schematic. I follow what’s in here. In my gut. My gut
>   always knows the way.

And from [Star Wars: Absolutely Everything You Need to Know](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Absolutely_Everything_You_Need_to_Know);

> **Q. Why does Chewie get mad when Luke tries to handcuff him?**
>
> A. It reminds him of his time as a slave of the Empire, which
>   imprisons and enslaves many Wookiees. Chewie was rescued by Han Solo,
>   and **pledged a Wookiee life debt to him in thanks**

Comment: Interesting. Ok well that answers it for me. Haven't been able to keep up with the novels now that I grow older. Now I kinda wish they had focused a little more on Chewie's post reaction to Han's death. Unless Chewie was not emotionally bound to Han at all, literally just by wookie life debt (which would also be interesting lol).

Comment: @DaWiseguy - I'd say "you should read the book" but, honestly...you really shouldn't. Check out the wookieepedia article on it for the plot. It's much better writing...

Comment: @NKCampbell I believe you. I hope the end of Star Wars isnt near.

Comment: @DaWiseguy - not even close. The other books outside of the Aftermath series have largely been very solid. Disney and the Lucasfilm Story Group are overall very good hands for Star Wars. The leadership seems to be populated with fans and that's a good thing

Comment: @NKCampbell I'll have to check them out then, I hope we don't see the end of the Wars in our lifetimes.

Comment: I hope people will stop referring to New Canon -- or 'noveau canon' -- as Disney canon. Disney had no say in what's canon or not. It was totally Lucasfilm's doing. Disney only enabled Lucasfilm to **reset** the canon because Disney had a lot of money and can weather the reduced licensing due to Legends-ization of the EU.